# Map with fine hatching using Python cartopy

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I try to create a geographical map using `contourf` including shaded areas (indicating significance).

Here is a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

lats = np.arange(-90, 91, 10)
lons = np.arange(-180, 181, 20)
data = np.sin(np.arange(len(lats)*len(lons))).reshape(len(lats), len(lons))

proj = ccrs.Robinson()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 7), subplot_kw={'projection': proj})
im = ax.contourf(
    lons, lats, data,
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
)
ax.contourf(
    lons, lats, data > data.mean(),
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    colors='none',
    levels=[.5, 1.5],
    hatches='///////',
)

ax.coastlines()
ax.set_global()
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, location='bottom')
```

What I struggle with is adjusting the properties of the hatching. It is way to coarse, I'd like to adjust this in order to be able to resolve finer structures. It is possible to do this by scaling the figure size:

```
scale = 10

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6*scale, 7*scale), subplot_kw={'projection': proj})
ax.contourf(
    lons, lats, data,
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
)
ax.contourf(
    lons, lats, data > data.mean(),
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    colors='none',
    levels=[.5, 1.5],
    hatches='///////',
)

ax.coastlines()
ax.set_global()
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, location='bottom')
```

But this literally messes up everything else (text, line width, etc.) and is probably not the best way of doing it in any case. **Is there a better way of adjusting the properties of the hatching in such a case?**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument `hatches` in `contourf` should be a list of size 2 since you have two levels. You can then increase the density of your hatching patterns by repeating the pattern, for instance, `density*'/'`. So overall the line should be `hatches=[density*'/',density*'/']`.
Below is an example when I set the density to 7:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

lats = np.arange(-90, 91, 10)
lons = np.arange(-180, 181, 20)
data = np.sin(np.arange(len(lats)*len(lons))).reshape(len(lats), len(lons))

proj = ccrs.Robinson()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 7), subplot_kw={'projection': proj})
im = ax.contourf(
    lons, lats, data,
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
density=7
ax.contourf(
    lons, lats, data > data.mean(),
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    colors='none',
    levels=[.5,1.5],
    hatches=[density*'/',density*'/'],
)

ax.coastlines()
ax.set_global()
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: Ah! I had misunderstood how the `hatches` works and was wondering why the multiple '////' did not change anything. It was simply interpreting the string as list and throwing everything after the first '/' way. Indeed I have two bounds, i.e. only one level. So its as simple as changing `hatches='///////'` -> `hatches=['///////']` Thanks a lot for the answer!